# in Linux, can the value of a symlink be longer than PATH_MAX?

Tags: linux, filesystems

As every child in kindergarten knows, a file path in Linux cannot be longer than `PATH_MAX` characters.

But experimenting on my system, the command

```
ln -s $(for i in {0..1024}; do printf dir/../; done)foobar foobar1
```

fails with the error message `File name too long`.

I don't quite understand why.  There is no long file name here, it is only the intended *contents* of the file `foobar1` that are very long. Nobody is even yet trying to *traverse* the contents of the symbolic link to get to the target.  Certainly I can have a file whose contents is much larger than `PATH_MAX`.

On the other hand, a command such as

```
for i in {0..4096}; do ln -s $i $(expr $i + 1); done
```

succeeds. Only if I tried to traverse the chain, does the system complain.

But I am not interested in *traversing* anything.  I am writing software that has to read the value of a symbolic link (without traversing) and I want to know if I need to account for very long values.

Where is it documented in Linux that this is not allowed?  Or is it file-system implementation dependent and can change?

Comment: I don't understand why you think that a path/filename combo of 7182 characters (be it relative or absolute) is the content of the file?

Comment: @tink symbolic link is a file that has `l` file-type in its inode, but otherwise its contents are the target of the link.

Comment: I must be missing something (despite the 20+ years of linux experience) ... you operate in a shell; assuming that foobar actually exists in the current working directory, and so does dir, you're instructing ln to try to expand a path of 7182  characters and create a sym-link to the file foobar called foobar1, which would then reside right next to it. This is failing because 7182 exceeds **grep PATH_MAX /usr/include/linux/limits.h** (4096 in my case). How this makes for __content__ I still don't understand.

Comment: @tink the contents of a symlink is that name of the target.  I don't know how to say it more clearly.  That is the nature of  symlink file.  Nobody is directing shell to expand anything, as dangling symlinks show, the system is not actually trying to follow the symlink to the target at the time of creation of the symlink, but only later when certain system calls (such as `open` but not `remove`) happen.

Comment: But the shell is still trying to evaluate a path of > 4096 characters ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to symlink fails with

```
ENAMETOOLONG (File name too long)
```

This is coming from the kernel. It's also filesystem dependent hence why you can't find SYMLINK_MAX defined anywhere. For instance...

**XFS**

```
if (pathlen < 0 || pathlen > MAXPATHLEN) {
  xfs_alert(mp, "%s: inode (%llu) bad symlink length (%lld)",
  __func__, (unsigned long long) ip->i_ino,
  .......
}
```

and MAXPATHLEN == 1024

**reiserfs**

```
item_len = ROUND_UP(strlen(symname));
if (item_len > MAX_DIRECT_ITEM_LEN(parent_dir->i_sb->s_blocksize)) {
  retval = -ENAMETOOLONG;
  .......
}
```

**ext2**

```
struct super_block * sb = dir->i_sb;
int err = -ENAMETOOLONG;
unsigned l = strlen(symname)+1;
.....
if (l > sb->s_blocksize)
   goto out;
....
return err;
```

A symlink should be usable anywhere a filename is so it makes logical sense for it to be less than PATH_MAX, it matters not what's inside it. From the symlink man page on Linux.

```
ENAMETOOLONG
    target or linkpath was too long.
```

This is vague because the filesystem defines it. The other limit you can hit is `_POSIX_SYMLINK_MAX`.

```
#define _POSIX_SYMLINK_MAX  255
```

To test it create the following two links in a directory. This one will succeed

```
ln -s foo Fh5LNDZYm2vUlf3jypJtAaX1ElqHZAF4ivsuq8sHyKVLDrYi4zR3T2QcXwS5TPRTys9aUxuh3qtnlNnFQGInmLiM7GK1xpN78ZbcD4JWizfPa7VWwhR4XWpvaJLHCIONUTC6A8fjNVfhv434vWckuKDzTacno0LE13mBVHuj5RDgJIkmW1zUcMMh5E38VisPxSN7BGxBVXHtn0cUPmZLmYSzGrOJqEJzimvwh2uDi8uXEOwBLbsfYlxBOz1kw8P
```

This one will fail

```
ln -s foo Fh5LNDZYm2vUlf3jypJtAaX1ElqHZAF4ivsuq8sHyKVLDrYi4zR3T2QcXwS5TPRTys9aUxuh3qtnlNnFQGInmLiM7GK1xpN78ZbcD4JWizfPa7VWwhR4XWpvaJLHCIONUTC6A8fjNVfhv434vWckuKDzTacno0LE13mBVHuj5RDgJIkmW1zUcMMh5E38VisPxSN7BGxBVXHtn0cUPmZLmYSzGrOJqEJzimvwh2uDi8uXEOwBLbsfYlxBOz1kw8Pk
```

One is 255 characters long and the other one is 256. In your question this command will work because each individual link has it's own inode and the name is short.

```
for i in {0..4096}; do ln -s $i $(expr $i + 1); done
```

Comment: thank you - I did scan the manpage for the symlink system call for `PATH_MAX` and there was noone so I went away.  It just says "too long" without mentioning `PATH_MAX`.   Thank you again.

Comment: actually for the record, the limit is `SYMLINK_MAX`

Comment: @MarkGaleck I've updated the answer. Based on what I found in the kernel it's completely filesystem dependent.